# What is the difference between positive matrix coefficients and negative matrix coefficients of an audio?

Tags: image-processing, signal-analysis, matrix

I have turned an audio file into an one dimensional array by using audioread function in matlab and found several positive and negative fractional coefficient values.What is the basic difference of this positive and negative sign in the matrix?

Comment: Just a nomenclature issue: Those numbers are not "coefficients", they are sample values of the sampled waveform.

Answer (score 1):

A sound wave is a pressure variation in a fluid (typically air) that varies with time and position. A microphone records this pressure variation: Positive means the local pressure is slightly higher than the static pressure and negative means it's slightly lower.

Comment: What is the meaning of this positive or negative sign?Does this mean the negative value is less than the positive one or does it indicate the direction only?

Comment: It indicates direction. For example if a microphone membrane is moving: positive denotes inward motion, negative denotes outward motion.